# CouchBase Editing documents from code

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, view, couchbase

IN order to test couchbase, I am needing to create servlet that edit in 1.000 JSON documents row '"flag": false' to '"flag":true'. How i can do this?

My view, that finds documents with row '"flag": false':

```
function (doc, meta) {  
    if (meta.type == "json" && doc.flag == false) {        
        emit(doc.flag, null);
    }
}
```

My servlet, that print results:

```
doGet(....
View view = client.getView("des1", "flag");
Query query = new Query();
query.setIncludeDocs(true);
ViewResponse result = client.query(view, query);
for(ViewRow row : result) {
  resp.getWriter().println(row.getId());  
}
```

Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the fields in the JSON document directly. What you must do is to retrieve the documents you want to update (you already get them from the view), convert them to a Java object, edit the "flag" property, serialize the Java object back to JSON and replace the document with the new one.
You can use GSON to take care of the conversion between a java object and json.